# CSS how to position an element in a middle (half height / vertical 50%) of another element

Tags: css, position, height, vertical-alignment, css-transforms

I'm looking forward to build a tooltip which is positioned next to the element, but in a middle of it. It's easy to put it over and under and position it in the horizontal center of an element. But is there a way to do so vertically (on the right or left side of an element, vertically positioned in a middle of that element height)?

For my purpose, height of the element is fixed (known) & height of tooltip is not, because it can contain various text content. And a tooltip can be a child of element.

However, I'm also curious about, how to do it when both heights are not fixed (unknown and can vary depending on content). By heights I understand element's and tooltip's height. Width can be known and fixed.

Comment: Nope, neither of below suits me

Comment: Take a look at my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32250727/491044

Comment: @elon If the answer below answers the question, please mark it as answered to help other users. Thanks.

Comment: @trgraglia Have put some more precision into this question

Comment: @elon, I added more examples to the codepen which is referenced.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is pretty late but I tried to make an example on codepen which shows a working example if I understood your question correctly.

http://codepen.io/trgraglia/pen/RWbKyj

Use CSS transform.

For example, `transform:translateX(-50%);`, will move an element left by 50% of ITSELF. Now you can align it to the parent with `position` and `bottom` or `top` or `left` or `right` and then move it by the dimensions of itself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not sure where the downvote comes from. Maybe i wasn't clear in my example. Top for example uses the parent height. You can set 50% top on the tooltip and then translateY -50% to center it. Feel free to explain the downvote.

Comment: This transform property rocks! In modern browsers the support for this CSS tag is pretty good, check your browser support though if you are going to use this (old IE doesn't work... same old story)

Comment: For me, this is the best solution.

Comment: Please do me a favor and put link to this SO question into your Pen, so I can find the question from bookmark to your pen.  Thanks.

Comment: @RaymondNaseef Done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

using CSS & jQuery-

### CSS

```
.div{
    top:50%
}
```

### jQuery

```
var divheight = $(.div).height() / 2;
$(.div).attr('style','margin-top:-'+divheight+'px;');
```

Comment: Question was all about CSS only solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know both heights, there are only two ways:

1. Set the parent `display: table` and children `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle`.
2. Using CSS3 Flexbox: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/ but with limited browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

If you are interested in this topic, here there is a good article with more tips:
http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

As you can see, the only way to vertical align an element without knowing its height and nor using CSS3 is using `display: table-cell`.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the height of the content the easiest way to center the tooltip is to set the `line-height` of tooltip to the height of content.You can see how i did that here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zN2m3/)