# how to put a button on top between two dives?

Tags: html, css, frontend

[image]

I want to make a design like this using css, but i don't know how to put this button on top between two `div`s, can anyone help me?

```
<div></div>
button
<div></div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Since you chose to not respond, I deleted my answer and suggest this possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940540/css-how-to-position-element-in-half-height-vertical-50

Answer (score 0):

Make the button style `position: absolute;` and define the `right` and `top` or `bottom` properties.

If you want the button to be fixed while scrolling, set `position: fixed;`

```css
#up{
background-color:#B7005D;
height:10vh;
width:100%;
}
#middle{
background-color:#E0E1E0;
height:40vh;
width:100%;
}
#floating-button{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #B7005D;
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #666;
}
```

```html
<div id="up"></div>
<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="floating-button"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use negative `margin-top` to pull your element up.