# How to make a link float on top left corner of a div

Tags: html, css

I want a link to float on top left corner of a div ,It should be on front also 
The purpose is to toggle the bootsrap collapse feature on click of that link .

below is my code.

```
<div id="Header" class="container container-fluid well-lg img-rounded shadow" style="background-color:whitesmoke">           
<div class="row" id="header">
    <div id="content">
        <div><a href="#" class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red">
           </a></div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            @*<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">*@
                <img src="~/Images/svc.jpg"  class="img-rounded"/>
            @*</a>*@
            <br />
            <b><i>Report </i></b>
         </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-lg hidden-md" >
            <hr style="visibility: hidden" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            @*@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, ViewBag.StateList as IEnumerable<selectlistitem>, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm", @onchange = "this.form.submit()" })*@            
          @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, ViewBag.StateList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control  input-md", @data_toggle = "tooltip", @title = "Select a State from here" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-lg hidden-md">
            <hr style="visibility: hidden" />
        </div>           
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12" >  
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.date, new { @class = "form-control input-md", @id = "dp1", @PlaceHolder = "Click Here to Select a Date", @data_toggle = "tooltip", @title = "Select a Date from here" }) 
            </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-lg hidden-md">
        <hr style="visibility: hidden" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-5 col-sm-12">          
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td>
                  <a href="@Url.Action("Back_Date", "BR")">
                      <img src="~/Images/oie_28455OHvJAUzA.png" class="img-rounded" height="45px" width="45px" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Go back to previous Date" />
                  </a>
              </td>
              <td>
                  <a href="@Url.Action("Next_Date", "BR")" >
                    <img src="~/Images/button-round-arrow-right-icon.png" class="img-rounded" height="45px" width="45px" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Go forward to Next Date"/>
                  </a>
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>               
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Its working but link is fully inside the div , I want it half outside and half inside. like this red plus sign 
[Click to see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UFKP.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to put a button on top between two dives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870666/how-to-put-a-button-on-top-between-two-dives)

Comment: your code is unusable . please provide a working snippet and/or just an example of code that replicates your problem

Answer (score 0):

i made a simple example of what i think you want. Using bootstrap `data-toggle`

let me know if this is what you are looking for

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px;
}

a.clickMe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="clickMe" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#text">+</a>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  <div id="text" class="collapse">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>
      Some text Some text Some tex
    </p>
    <p>
      Some text Some text Some tex
    </p>
    <p>
      Some text Some text Some tex
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```